# Contact Layout Editor- Create New Block not working

Tags: contacts, contact-layout-editor

I've just installed Contact layout Editor and can't get the Add Block option to work
[image]

I'd assumed this would allow me to create a custom block with fields from different sets- but I'm clicking on the option and nothing happens.

Civi 5.29.1
CLE 1.7.2
Angular Profiles 4.7.31-1.1.2
Drpl 7.78

Quite happy to accept this is user error/ignorance. Anyone got any experience of installing/ configuring layouts?

Editting in response to Pradeep's question.
Following Console Error appears when hitting Add Block

```
angular.js:14199 TypeError: designerDialog.$el.dialog is not a function
at child.onRender (eval at <anonymous> (jquery.min.js?qnn83t:2), <anonymous>:67:26)
at child.triggerMethod (eval at <anonymous> (jquery.min.js?qnn83t:2), <anonymous>:565:21)
at child.render (eval at <anonymous> (jquery.min.js?qnn83t:2), <anonymous>:1462:10)
at child.render (eval at <anonymous> (jquery.min.js?qnn83t:2), <anonymous>:1920:55)
at child.r [as render] (lodash.min.js?qnn83t:25)
at newProfile (angular-modules.740a618b49edbce232bff241f218f693.js?qnn83t:381)
at angular.js:16696
at m.$eval (angular.js:17994)
at m.$digest (angular.js:17808)
at m.$apply (angular.js:18102)
```

Comment: Do you see any js error in browser console?

Comment: Ticket updated with JS Error Code- thank for the suggestion!

Comment: Looks like js file is not invoked, can you check if there are any js file 500 errors